# Опять запятая в ССП (?)

Tags: запятые, ссп

Возник вопрос о жителях Болгара(,) и говорили о них: "Это народ..."
Вроде бы нужна запятая в скобках. Или я что-то не понимаю?
Года два назад у меня же был "похожий" вопрос, но хочется точно утвердиться в этой запятой.

Comment: Странно, неужели некому ответить на простой (для знающих) вопрос?

Comment: И в чём же сомнения, если Вы сами сказали, что это ССП? Запятая разделяет простые предложения, а не отвечают Вам, потому что сомнение вызывает само предложение.

Comment: Я потому и поставил ССП с вопросом из-за сомнений (даже в этом). И не очень понятно, чем вызывает сомнение само предложение.